# Are there reports of "Unable to load posts. Retry" in a Google Space?

Tags: google-spaces

I have two spaces in Google Spaces:

[image]

My problem is that in the first one, in which I and one more person have been posting for weeks, Google is "Unable to load posts" and offers to "retry":

[image]

My second space is working just fine:

[image]

Has this problem been reported anywhere?
["Unable to load posts. Retry"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20load%20posts.%20Retry%22) is a no-hitter on Google.

I have the same problem using the Android app. I'll spare you the snapshots - the error message there is ["Error fetching the posts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Error%20fetching%20the%20posts%22%20%2BSpaces) (no hits with +Spaces on Google).

Are there any public reports of this kind? Is Google losing data? (The latter question may be a little provocative, but I haven't been able to access this space for weeks now, so I am wondering quite a bit.)

I have reported this through the "Send feedback" menu option in Google Spaces some weeks ago, but you are not supposed to obtain direct feedback from the developers. And obviously, it is still not working. What else are useful places to report this?

(Edit: It is working again.)

Answer (score 1):

> What else are useful places to report this?

## Short answer

I suggest you to try first the [Google+ Help](https://plus.google.com/communities/115758385206378551362) Community.

## Extended answer

You could try places participating in the [Google Top Contributor Program](http://topcontributor.withgoogle.com):

- Help on Social
- Google Help Forums and Communities
- Google Cloud Connet

### Help on social

Post a tweet including #gHelp

### Google Help Forums and Communities

Most of the Google web applications for consumers have a help forum or Google+ Community. As I mentioned in the short answer, I suggest you to try first the Google+ Help Community, but there are several alternatives. To find them

1. Go to a Google product that you use most

   - http://www.google.com
   - http://gmail.com
   - http://hangouts.google.com
   - ...
2. Click on Settings / Menu (hamburger/three strips button) > Help
3. Click on Help Forum

### Google Cloud Connect

If you have a G Suite account you could try [Google Cloud Connect](https://connect.googleforwork.com)

Comment: This answer looked good at first. But: 1. "Welcome to the Google+ Help Community,  a place for your Google+ related questions." This community does not seem to be concerned with questions about Google Spaces. 2. The "Google Top Contributor Program" is for people who want to help, rather than get help. 3. Google Spaces does not have a help forum or community - at least I cannot find one using the instructions provided. 4. I do not habe a G Suite account.